# Остановить копирование файлов при достижение определённого размера папки

Tags: c#

Подскажите как добавить проверку на размер папки ( куда копируются файлы )
сделать ограничение копирование ( при определённом размере остановить копирование ).

На данном примере:

```
public static void CopyDirectory(string source, string target)
{
    var stack = new Stack<Folders>();
    stack.Push(new Folders(source, target));

    while (stack.Count > 0)
    {
        var folders = stack.Pop();
        Directory.CreateDirectory(folders.Target);
        foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(folders.Source, "*.*"))
        {
            File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(folders.Target, Path.GetFileName(file)));
        }

        foreach (var folder in Directory.GetDirectories(folders.Source))
        {
            stack.Push(new Folders(folder, Path.Combine(folders.Target, Path.GetFileName(folder))));
        }
    }
}

public class Folders
{
    public string Source { get; private set; }
    public string Target { get; private set; }

    public Folders(string source, string target)
    {
        Source = source;
        Target = target;
    }
}
```

Я так полагаю если и делать проверку то внутри:

```
foreach (var folder in Directory.GetDirectories(folders.Source))
{
  stack.Push(new Folders(folder, Path.Combine(folders.Target, Path.GetFileName(folder))));
}
```

Правильно ?

Из примеров я брал этот код:

```
public static long GetDirSize(string path)
{
  try
  {
     return Directory.EnumerateFiles(path).Sum(x => new FileInfo(x).Length) +  
            Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path).Sum(x => GetDirSize(x));
  }
  catch
  {
     return 0;
  }
}
```

И далее пробовал сделать такую проверку: ( для теста )

```
long Low = 0, Limit = 100000000;
if (Low + GetDirSize(target) > Limit)
{
   stack.Push(new Folders(folder, Path.Combine(folders.Target, Path.GetFileName(folder))));
}
```

Не исключаю тот факт что я не правильно сделал ( всё может быть =) )
Прощу помочь знающих.

Comment: @Streletz, Там пример через DirectoryInfo не подходит, придётся переделывать, а не охота =)

Comment: Если минусуете, то хоть напишите из-за чего! Не вежливо как-то

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто после каждого скопированого файла проверяешь размер папки. То есть проверку нужно зашить внутрь цикла.

Если Папка уже больше - прерываешь цикл копирования (`break;` если не ошибаюсь).

Если хочешь что бы точно был размер папки меньше -- делаешь наоборот:

проверяешь размер папки и добавляешь к нему размер файла который ты собираешся копировать. Если больше -- то прерываешь процесс копирования. Если меньше - копируешь.

ну... в принципе и все...

```
public static void CopyDirectory(string source, string target, long maxSize)
{
    var stack = new Stack<Folders>();
    stack.Push(new Folders(source, target));

    while (stack.Count > 0)
    {
        var folders = stack.Pop();
        Directory.CreateDirectory(folders.Target);
        foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(folders.Source, "*.*"))
        {
            File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(folders.Target, Path.GetFileName(file)));

            var size = GetDirSize(target);
            if (size> maxSize) return;// выходим из метода
        }

        foreach (var folder in Directory.GetDirectories(folders.Source))
        {
            stack.Push(new Folders(folder, Path.Combine(folders.Target, Path.GetFileName(folder))));

            var size = GetDirSize(target);
            if (size > maxSize) return;// выходим из метода
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Так я по сути это и делал же внутрь цикла..Как правильно сделать проверку?

Comment: я не вижу в первом коде что бы ты хоть где-нибудь использовал свой метод GetDirSize() и так же не вижу что бы ты пытался вызвать break внутри цикла если размер больше. Где ты это делал?

Comment: Читайте 1-ый пост, последний текст ( с кодом ) там я и добавлял его.

Comment: короче, мне влом разбиратся. Я кинул код который должен быть

Comment: если будет работать не так как нужно исправь на вторую логику которую я описывал текстом.

Comment: Способ работает, но файлы собираются как улитка ( очень медленно ) теперь. Как проверка влияет на такую низкую работу? Что можно сделать?

Comment: Создай переменную в которую будешь записывать размер файла который ты уже скопировал. Это будет работать значительно быстрее. Так же сделай вложенный цикл: внешний цикл перебирает каждую категорию, внутренний - каждый файл в этой категории. И так по файлу ты будешь копировать и при этом будешь взвешивать каждый отдельный файл и добавлять его вес в ту переменную. Вместо того что бы сотни раз взвешивать всю папку (то есть автоматически взвешивать каждый файл во всех вложенных категориях) после копирования каждого отдельного файла..

Comment: Сначала пробуй, а если будет не получатся - создай новый вопрос и опиши что конкретно не выходит и тебе кто-то поможет. Здесь помогают делать, а не делают вместо тебя ;)